# Unable to convert input xml file content to a DataSet. Requested value 'ConnectionStrings' was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dataset, app-code

I have a problem with the visual studio.
I user visual studio 2015 and choose framework 4.5 and create an empty website.
then I add Dataset.xsd to my project (in App_Code) and then by using server explorer I add my database tables to the dataset.
with drag and drop it makes connection string in web.config and when I Build solution I get this Error. I attached a screenshot.
Attention: I used this method many times and I have no problem before,
but recently I get Error.
Please Help ME.
Thanks.

Comment: Where is the screenshot?

Comment: Can you add the snippet of web.config ?

Answer (score 0):

Below article discusses options about loading the contents of a DataSet from an XML From Microsoft:

[[Link]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd(VS.71).aspx)

Kindly refer to it, and if didn't help here is a microsoft community forums that discussed this issue

[[Link 2]](https://forums.asp.net/t/1108730.aspx?Error%20193%20Unable%20to%20convert%20input%20xml%20file%20content%20to%20a%20DataSet%20Requested%20value%20ConnectionStrings%20was%20not%20found%20)

Comment: at first thank you for your attention, I read that article but I could not find out what should I do exactly yo resolve my problem. would you please help me step by step to resolve?

Comment: sure, the problem is referring to web.config , try to check it if it contains the correct syntax to check it try creating a normal page just for testing the connection, if it didn't work check the name of dB,Username and Pass

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in DataSet.xsd file with TableAdapter's connection string which you've added in Dataset by drag and drop.

1. open DataSet.xsd file in xml editor
2. remove connection string which have property AppSettingsObjectName="web.config"
3. again open the Dataset with normal editor.
4. now delete the TableAdapter which you have added by drag and drop
5. Add the TableAdapter again in dataset by right click option [See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjs4f.png)